# c copying first letter of ptr

Tags: c, pointers

I have no idea what is wrong with the following code. I perused stackoverflow without finding much assistance.

```
char * abbreviate_name( const char * full_name) {

int length = strlen(full_name) + 1;
char * final = malloc(length);
*answer = '\0';
char ptr[51];

// above is where I declare all my variables
strncpy(ptr, full_name, length); // copy full_name because it is a const

// ...

final = &ptr[1]; // this line copies all of ptr when I do a prinf on it
```

I'm just wondering how to get the first letter of ptr. 
I tried playing with the ptrs and addresses and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The first character of `full_name` is `full_name[0]`.

Comment: What is `answer` that you can do `*answer = '\0';`?  It must be a global variable since it isn't declared in the function.  Avoid global variables — or don't post approximations to the code your trying to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get the first char of a pointer you can either go `*ptr` or `ptr[0]`.

Your code has other problems though, assign to final doesn't copy, it just points final to another location, in this case you are going to point to a stack variable and it's going to fail badly.

instead, just `strcpy` into final and get rid of "ptr"

Answer (score 1):

```
final[0] = ptr[0];
*final   = *ptr;
final[0] = *ptr;
*final   = ptr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, in addition to Keith's answer, accomplish the allocation and copy of `full_name` to `final` in one step by making use of `strdup`:

```
char *abbreviate_name (const char *full_name) {

    char *final = strdup (full_name);

    ...
```

`strdup` will call `malloc` to dynamically allocate storage sufficient to hold `full_name`. Just as if you had used `malloc`, you are responsible for freeing the memory when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably shooting in the dark and writing an answer which is very much prone to down-votes, but let me begin.

Probably OP is looking for a function which provides and abbreviated version of a string, thus first letter of each of the given words in a string ( full_string ). reason I thought this because of char * return type and function name.

```
char * abbreviate_name( const char * full_name) ;
```

If I am correct in understanding the question, then you are probably looking for

> strtok

and here is a snippet for extracting what you are looking for

```
    char *str1, *saveptr1, *token ;
    for ( str1 = full_name; ;  str1 = NULL) {
            token = strtok_r(str1, " " , &saveptr1); // delimited with " " 
            if ( token == NULL ) {
                    break; // break once no tokens available
            }
            printf("%c ",  *token); // Extract first letter for each word, which probably form the abbreviated string you are looking for
    }
```